# NDSolve WhenEvent Partial Evaluation of a Function

Tags: differential-equations, equation-solving, numerical-integration

I want to obtain an intermediate result from `NDSolve` using `WhenEvent`.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure what the question is asking, but here is a way to get the solutions midway, at the time of the event (i.e. "break the evaluation").  I don't think it's possible to remove variables from the `NDSolve` integration, other than to stop integration and restart with a new command that picks up at the stopping point.  So they will continue to be integrated, but they can be ignored.

```
Block[{
  m1 = 1,
  m2 = 1,
  m3 = 1,
  δ12 = (x1[t] - x2[t] + 0.1),
  δ23 = (x2[t] - x3[t] + 0.1),
  F12 = 100 δ12 + Sin[10 t],
  F23 = 150 δ23 + Sin[10 t],
  eq1 = (m1) x1''[t] == -F12,
  eq2 = (m2) x2''[t] == F12 - F23,
  eq3 = (m3) x3''[t] == F23},
 des = {eq1, eq2, eq3};
 ICs = {x1[0] == 0, x2[0] == 0.1, x3[0] == 0.2, x1'[0] == 0.4, 
   x2'[0] == 0, x3'[0] == 0};
 {sol} = NDSolve[{des, ICs, 
    WhenEvent[(x1[t] - x2[t] + 0.1) == 0.1 && x1'[t] < x2'[t] < x3'[t], 
     sol1 = NDSolve`ProcessSolutions[NDSolve`Self];  (* cull the current solutions *)
     "RemoveEvent"]},
   {x1, x2, x3, x1', x2', x3'}, {t, 0, 5}, 
   MaxSteps -> Infinity, AccuracyGoal -> 5, 
   Method -> {Automatic, "DiscontinuityProcessing" -> False}]
 ]
(*
  {{x1 -> InterpolatingFunction[{{0., 5.}}, <>], 
    ..., 
    Derivative[1][x3] -> InterpolatingFunction[{{0., 5.}}, <>]}}
*)
```

Here is the partial solution (where the event "break[s] the evaluation"):

```
sol1
(*
  {x1 -> InterpolatingFunction[{{0., 1.85508}}, <>], 
   ..., 
   Derivative[1][x3] -> InterpolatingFunction[{{0., 1.85508}}, <>]}
*)
```

`` NDSolve`Self `` refers to the `` NDSolve`StateData[] `` object representing the problem.  One can read about such object in the tutorial
[Components and Data Structures](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/NDSolveStateData.html).